# Linear Dependence Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook presents the following theorem for linear dependence:

---

[image]

---

Could someone please help me understand why it's important that $\vec{v_1} \ne \vec{0}$?

The textbook doesn't clarify this part of the theorem and instead assumes that it's clear, but it really isn't (at least to me).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the result isn't true if you allow $\mathbf v_1=\mathbf 0$.  Consider $\mathbf v_1=\mathbf 0$, and $\mathbf v_2\neq\mathbf 0$. Then the indexed set $\{\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2\}$ is linearly dependent, but $\mathbf v_2\neq \alpha\mathbf v_1$ for any scalar $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

A set containing the zero-vector $v_0=0$ is always linear dependant.

Now consider the set $S=\{v_1,v_2\}=\{\vec{0},\vec{1}\}$, as subset of the $ℝ$-vector space $ℝ$. The theorem, as it is stated by the author, cannot be used, because $S$ does not fulfil the requirements.

If the author did not state $v_1\neq0$, then $S$ would be linear independent by the theorem, as there is no α such that: 
$$ αv_1 = v_2 \qquad ⇔ \qquad α\vec{0} = \vec{1}.$$

But that is simply a false statement.

---

It is not necessary to exclude $v_i\neq0$ for $i>1$, because the theorem holds for that case as well. That can be best seen with an example:
Let $$S_2=\{(1,0),(0,1),(0,0),(-1,-1)\}⊂ℝ^2.$$
Using the theorem with $j=3$ we have: 
$$α_1(1,0)+α_2(0,1)\overset{!}{=}(0,0).$$
With $α_1=α_2=0$ we found such a linear combination.

---

Back to the first set $S=\{\vec{0},\vec{1}\}$: With the previous statement in mind, we can now use the Theorem, as formulated by the author, on the set $\tilde{S}:=\{\vec{1},\vec{0}\}$. Simply because sets don't care about order, and we can just rename/reorder the vectors inside. 
Hence, $S$ is linear dependant.